# Is it possible to modify an Elated plugin portfolio-list template in such a way that it will not conflict with future plugin updates?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

I recognize that this is a bit specific but I'm hoping there's some more general explanation for modifying plugin templates that can be applied here.

Here are the specifics:

I need to modify a plugin template my client purchased. The template is located here:

```
wp-content/plugins/eltd-core/post-types/portfolio/shortcodes/portfolio-list/templates/standard.php
```

If I modify that file, I see the change reflected in the web page output I see in my browser. But I don't want to modify this. I want to override it.

I've tried following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19709371/6763239) and copying that file into the theme directory both here:

```
wp-content/themes/malmo/standard.php
```

and here:

```
wp-content/themes/malmo/framework/modules/portfolio/shortcodes/portfolio-list/templates/standard.php
```

But my modifications of the copied file had no impact on the web page output in either case. I suspect the issue is that the plugin and theme are not configured in a way to support overriding the template in this way.

I should also mention that I looked into modifying the template using VisualComposer in the dashboard but that that did not appear possible.

I want to make sure I rule out all the less invasive options before I resort to the brute force option of just modifying the underlying plugin template.

Comment: if a plugin do not explicitly document ways of "enhancing" it, than whatever you do will be equivalent to forking it, it will just be a difference between the likeliness of the fork causing actual problem in future updates

Comment: @MarkKaplun That was my suspicion. Thanks for confirming.